# Iptables change destination address postrouting

Tags: linux, ip-address, iptables, nat

I have to change the destination address of my packets before they send...
Looking on the web I saw that with Iptables is possible to change the destination address of the packets in prerouting.
Can you help me?
I would something like

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 239.0.2.4 -o wlan0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.3
```

My problem is that a relay of my rtsp local server accepts only a multicast ip-address but I would that the packets are sent with a classical ip-address.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can change the destination address in `PREROUTING`, and source address in `POSTROUTING`.

The rationale is that during the `POSTROUTING` chain, the routing decision has already taken place, and altering the destination address now would be nonsensical. Either the decision would be the same (in which case you can use the `PREROUTING` chain), or it would be different, in which case you really want a policy route.